Modifying Bluetooth GATT Configurator Report Map Characteristics in SiLabs - Simplicity studio v5
As part of my application,I am working with SiLabs and following example of this text with my deice EFR32BG22 and tool Simplicity Studio V5.
I need to add a digitizer descriptor to the Bluetooth GATT Configurator's Report Map characteristic(in .sclp file). The goal is to adjust the characteristic's behavior dynamically to support the digitizer HID functionality
Here's what I have tried so far:
Modified the initial value of the mouse descriptor Report Map characteristic by padding  it with my digitizer descriptor (I also tried without padding- only digitizer descriptor).
and Connected the BLE device to the host, but after connection, the host side reports a Driver Error while connecting BLE and does not recognize the functionality as intended.
I suspect the issue might be related to:

Incorrect formatting of the Report Map descriptor.
BLE stack configuration issues in Simplicity Studio.
Limitations in how the GATT Configurator handles custom descriptors.

Can someone guide me on:

How to correctly modify the initial value of the Report Map characteristic to include a digitizer descriptor?

Any specific steps or configurations in Simplicity Studio that might help resolve this issue?



Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Silabs has its own community forum, which is much more appropriate for this type of question: https://community.silabs.com/

Yes, I already posted on that but no reply.

Maybe you could post your report map?
